# General Question on limit of function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I'm reading an example in a book about how to find the limit of a function using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definition. But I'm confused about one part of the example.

Example: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}x^2=4$$
for every $\epsilon>0$, we must find a $\delta>0$ such that when $0<|x-2|<\delta$, we have $$|f(x)-4|<\epsilon$$ Set $$\delta = \min \{\frac{\epsilon}{5},1\}$$ and then the example go on solving for the limit.

My question: I understand every part and definition except why they set $\delta$ to be the min of $\{\frac{\epsilon}{5},1\}$, they didn't really explain where did the 5 come from or why are we setting $\delta$ to be the min of those 2 values, and it is baffling for me since that seems to be a critical part.

Can someone tell me what am I missing? thanks!

Comment: They set it like that because it works, but you do not know why until you read on to the end and you will see why this decision is useful at each point.

Comment: thanks for your response I understand how the 5 comes to play when canceling out the 5 and having the epsilon inequality satisfied. but it only makes sense to pick the 5 after solving the inequality involves epsilon. I think I am still confused about how they decided to pick delta to be epsilon/5 before solving the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f(x)=x^2$. Therefore, $|f(x)-4|=|x^2-4| = |x-2|\cdot |x+2|$, We are considering limit at point $2$, When $x < 3$, we have $|f(x)-4| = |x-2| \cdot |x+2| < |x-2|\cdot |3+2|$. Now, given $\epsilon > 0$ if we chose $\delta = \min \{1, \frac{\epsilon}{5}\}$, then $|x-2| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-4|< \epsilon$.

Here $1=|3-2|$ and $5=3+2$. We have chosen $3$ a point near $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if $\delta=\min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{5},1\right\}$ then

$|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$ and also $|x-2|<1$.

But  $|x-2|<1$ is equivalent to $-1<x-2<1$. So if we add $4$ we get that

$3<x+2<5$, so $|x+2|<5$

Therefore, we can conclude that if $0<|x-2|<\delta$ then $|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$ and $|x+2|<5$. So the product of the two inequalities gives us $|x^2-4|<\epsilon$.